# regex dictionary replacement working with only some entries (python). why?

Tags: python, regex

When I run the below code the output is:

> [HCO3-], [Ca+], [potassium ion concentration+], [Cl-].  HCO3-, Ca+,
>   potassium ion concentration+, Cl-.

But it should be:

> Bicarbonate ion concentration, Calcium ion concentration, potassium
>   ion concentration, chloride ion concentration.  Bicarbonate ions,
>   Calcium ions, potassium ions, chloride ions.

Why is the function converting parts of the string but not the whole thing?

Code:

```
### imports
    import re

### definitions  
    def concentration_expansion(text):
        '''expand concentration names'''
        swaps = {
            '[Cl-]': 'chloride ion concentration', '[K+]': 'potassium ion concentration',
            '[Ca+]': 'Calcium ion concentration', '[HCO3-]': 'Bicarbonate ion concentration',
            }

        initial = text
        for key in swaps:
            pattern = r'\b' + '{}'.format(key) + r'\b'
            text = re.sub(pattern, swaps.get(key), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        return text

    def ion_abbrev(text):
        '''expand ion names'''
        swaps = {
            'Cl-': 'chloride ions', 'K+': 'potassium ions',
            'Ca+': 'Calcium ions', 'HCO3-': 'Bicarbonate ions',
            }

        initial = text
        for key in swaps:
            pattern = r'\b' + '{}'.format(key) + r'\b'
            text = re.sub(pattern, swaps.get(key), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        return text

### program   
    text = '''
    [HCO3-], [Ca+], [K+], [Cl-].  HCO3-, Ca+, K+, Cl-.
    '''

    text = concentration_expansion(text)

    print(text)
```

Comment: Your keywords start/end with special chars, and `\b` meaning is context-depedent. Use either unambiguous word boundaries or whitespace boundaries.